# How to execute multiple animation at same time

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to know how I do to run two animations at the same time

```
 public async void OnClicked2Async(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        btn_login.SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, true);
        await btn_login.TranslateTo(0, 175, 1000); 
        await btn_novaconta.TranslateTo(0, -60, 1000); 
    }
```

This is my code

Comment: just remove first await word

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can "group" animations by adding `Animation` instances to a parent/master `Animation` instance and then committing them:

```
var button1Anim = new Animation(_ => button1.TranslateTo(0, 175, 1000));
var button2Anim = new Animation(_ => button2.TranslateTo(0, 175, 1000));
var masterAnimation = new Animation
{
    { 0, 1, button1Anim },
    { 0, 1, button2Anim }
};
masterAnimation.Commit(this, "MyAnim");
```

Re: [Custom Animations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom)

Comment: What are you mean at here { 0, 1, } ??

Comment: `Animation that begins at beginAt and finishes at finishAt.` Each child animation you add to the parent animation has a start/end time within that parent

Comment: Its miliseconds?

Comment: @Winteriscoming `The argument values must be between 0 and 1, and represent the relative period within the parent animation that the specified child animation will be active.` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom