# How to make animation for multiple control in parallel with fly in from bottom effect in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am making a multiple choice quiz app in xamarin forms as like attached image[https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3A5d.jpg]. when i click next button then next question and answer is coming but i want to put animation on that. I want when i clicked on "next" button four option will come from bottom in fly in effect.any effect is acceptable, no issue. But my actual issue is when i used await TranslateTo or ScaleTo in all button it will happen but the effect is coming one by one. After first button effect complete then second is starting, But i need same effect in all 4 button in same time. if any body suggest it can be helpful to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute multiple animation at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798071/how-to-execute-multiple-animation-at-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can add Animations to a parent Animation and then execute all of them togethers.

Here your ask is already answered:
[How to execute multiple animation at same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798071/how-to-execute-multiple-animation-at-same-time)

Comment: Its working but after moves of buttons how to placed them in original location?